Trying to run drl an turn signals 2 switches
I'm trying to run daytime running lights an turn signals - so I have a switch for drl lights an a switch for turn signals - how would I wire it so the drl shut off when the turn signal is activated? Do I use two 5 pin relays? Or is 1 relay capable of 2 switches an able to activate drl an turn signals?
